# Сравнить элементы списка кортежа со словарем

Tags: python, list, кортежи

Столкнулся с такой задачей. Есть список кортежей и словарь

```
list1 = [(2, 4, 2, 1, 0), (4, 2, 1, 0), (1, 1, 0), (4, 1), (1, 4, 1), (1, 1)]
dict1 = {
  (1,1):'1',
  (7,2):'2' ,
  (1,0):'3',
  (4,2):'4',
  (4,1):'5',
  (2,1):'6',
  (2,4):'7'
}
d_to_list =list(dict1.keys())
```

Что нужно сделать:
из первого элемента списка кортежей получить пары элементов `[0][1], [1][2], [1][3]`...  Получиться должно:
`(2, 4),(4, 2),(2, 1),(1, 0)` и сравнить с `d_to_list`
из второго элемента списка кортежей достать комбинации `(4, 2),(2, 1),(1, 0)` и сравнить с `d_to_list`
и так далее.

Comment: И в чём сложность? Примерно по такому принципу: `x = (2, 4, 2, 1, 0);
[(a,b) for a,b in zip(x, x[1:])]`

Comment: @CrazyElf А со всем списком кортежей как быть?

Comment: Вы не умеете перебирать элементы списка? И не важно что в списке, перебор всегда выглядит одинаково - через `for`. Я уже писал целиком решения, хватит, вы должны и сами думать, тут ничего сложного, просто составить решение из простых довольно элементов.